# I don't understand this define macro with replication

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, operator-precedence

I have SystemVerilog code in which replication is used that I don't understand. Please be thorough with your answer.

```
parameter WIDTH = 6;
logic [WIDTH-1:0] flag, flag2;

`define ZERO_X(n, m) {{m-$bits(n){1'b0}}, (n)}

assign flag = flag2 - `ZERO_X(1'b1, WIDTH);
```

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to perform simple text substitution in this expression.  Replace `n` with `1'b1` and `m` with `WIDTH`.  So this:

```
`ZERO_X(1'b1, WIDTH)
```

becomes:

```
{{WIDTH-$bits(1'b1){1'b0}}, (1'b1)}
```

Replace `WIDTH` with `6`:

```
{{6-$bits(1'b1){1'b0}}, 1'b1}
```

`$bits(1'b1)` evaluates to `1`:

```
{{(6-1){1'b0}}, 1'b1}
```

`6-1` is just `5`:

```
{{5{1'b0}}, 1'b1}
```

`{5{1'b0}}` replicates `1'b0` out to 5 0's:

```
{5'b0_0000, 1'b1}
```

Then simple concatenation:

```
6'b00_0001
```

Thus, this line:

```
assign flag = flag2 - `ZERO_X(1'b1, WIDTH);
```

evaluates to:

```
assign flag = flag2 - 6'b00_0001;
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is trying to 0-extend its operand to WIDTH and is totally unnecessary. By Verilog rules, the `1'b1` operand already gets extended to the width of the largest operand in the context of the expression it's written in.

```
assign flag = flag2 - 1'b1;
```

But if you want to clearly show that extension, you could write an explicit cast:

```
assign flag = flag2 - WIDTH'(1'b1);
```